# How to verify Google user's password using Google API

Tags: c#, .net, google-api, gmail, google-apps

We've a list of Google Apps for Work users.
We'd like the user to fill his email and his password fields before we send him to another page.

We need a way to verify her password using Google API.
Note that we don't need to bind our application to this user's account.

We just need to give Google a username/password combination and receive an answer of:

"Yes, they match" or "No, they don't match"

Comment: I would imagine that is not possible, as Google would very much prefer you to redirect the user to their page to get them to log in (so that the user's credentials are only supplied to Google, not to you). Google will then authenticate them, and redirect back to your page with a success/failure result.

Comment: The would never be possible, as if you then chose to try and brute force it they would have to lock that User's account, meaning that you could use the Google API to lock anyone's account you pleased.

Comment: We're the admins of Google Apps for Work subscription and these accounts we'd like to verify are our company's employees

Comment: I see what you mean, if they limited the use of such a method to a specific instance of GAfW, but I don't know if Google's internal structure grants itself to that, and I'd still be surprised to find it.